# Add child layout keeping header and footer common on all layouts in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

On all layouts I have a header and footer in common, how do I change the in between layout at runtime?

main_latout.xml-

> ```
>     <RelativeLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
> <include 
>     android:id="@+id/header"
>     layout="@layout/mytask_header"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
>
> <include 
>     android:id="@+id/footer"
>     layout="@layout/mytask_footer_ads"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
>
> <RelativeLayout 
>     android:id="@+id/common_place_for_xml"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_below="@id/header"
>     android:layout_above="@id/footer"
>     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
>
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

I want to change other layout in the `RelativeLayout` with id `common_place_for_xml` ?
I am newbie? Please help.

Comment: It seems a perfect study case for using a Fragment.

Comment: read about fragments here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Fragments can help you big time !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want, but I'll try to help.

Try giving your outer RelativeLayout an id, such as "parentLayout", and another XML file with the name newLayout which will be replacing your "common_place_for_xml" layout.

Then at runtime try:

```
RelativeLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
RelativeLayout childLayout = parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.common_place_for_xml);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) childLayout.getLayoutParams();
int index = parentLayout.indexOfChild(childLayout);
parentLayout.removeView(childLayout);
RelativeLayout newLayout = findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
parentLayout.addView(newLayout, index);
newLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add views to your relative layout in run time. Here's a sample:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.common_place_for_xml);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button dummy = new Button(this);
dummy.setText("Hello");
dummy.setLayoutParams(params);
relativeLayout.addView(dummy);
```